# Calling a different host from Spring Controller

Tags: spring, controller, request, mapping, response

My localhost is : http://localhost:8585/api/getproducts where i use @Requestmapping(/api/getproducts) in my ProductController to get to my product page.

On click of a button, i need to call an api on a different host :
http://10.120.130.22:9292/ and i tried to use the below code in a new Controller to call the host:

```
@RequestMapping("Trainer/reStaff/")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody response(@RequestParam("trainingId") final int trainingId, HttpServletRequest request)
                                                                                    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        String hostname="http://10.120.130.22:9292/";
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response=null;

        try{
            String uri=hostname+"Trainer/reStaff/?trainingId="+trainingId;
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
                System.out.println(responseData+"\n");              
            else
                System.out.println("Error :" + responseData+"\n");


        }finally {
            httpclient.close();
            response.close();
        }
```

But i get the error :

## HTTP Status 404 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The requested resource is not available.

How do i call the new host from my controller?

Comment: Remove the  extra **/**  before query param from url                                                                   
        String uri=hostname+"Trainer/reStaff?trainingId="+trainingId;

Comment: Does the URL work when you enter it in the browser?

Comment: When i enter the URL in browser, it gives this error : {"response":{"error":"Referer Url domain doesn't match with host domain"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood how this works. We need to pass the url through httpPost in the service layer :

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(hostUri);
        JsonObject jsonResponse = null;

```
    try {
        String httpRequestBody = jsonRequestBuilder.build().toString();
        logger.info("Request Body: " + httpRequestBody);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager).build();
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(httpRequestBody));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        logger.debug("Response Status: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        StringBuffer httpResponseBody = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            httpResponseBody.append(line);
        }
        logger.info("Response Body: " + httpResponseBody.toString());
        JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(httpResponseBody.toString()));
        jsonResponse = jsonReader.readObject();
        jsonReader.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error occurred while invoking POST on ep: " + hostUrl, ex);
    } finally {
        httpPost.releaseConnection();
    }
    logger.debug("Exiting");
    return jsonResponse;
```